# How can I turn off /deep/ combinator deprecation warnings in Chrome's console?

Tags: google-chrome, polymer, shadow-dom

When writing Polymer proof-of-concepts, I keep getting:

```
/deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
```

in the console of Google Chrome.

Is there a way to not get this warning with every page load?

Comment: You can avoid using `/deep/`, disable JavaScript, or use an older version of Chrome. It's been deprecated since April. This link might be useful: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/78

Comment: Disable JavaScript? That's exactly what the undertaker told John Cena!

Comment: To echo the part that @TylerH said about deprecation, I’ve been involved in the Shadow DOM discussions among the browser implementors and spec authors and can tell you that `/deep/` is definitely on the chopping block. The deprecation is short-term; it’s out of the spec already, and will eventually disappear from Chrome completely. So it’s not prudent to use it for anything new you’re deploying, and it will eventually break in any existing stuff you might have already deployed.

Comment: Well, Good news here is that if you are just using already built polymer/google web components in your proof-of-concepts and not using /deep/ combinator yourself in your newly build webcomponents, this warning will go away as soon as polymer upgrades their components to not use /deep/ and starts using [custom css properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html) everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You may be seeing this error because you are using the class method of applying layouts. If you switch to using Custom CSS mixins then you don't get the error.

So just import:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
```

and not **classes/iron-flex-layout.html** (it appears to be the inclusion of this file that causes the warning)

Then use:

```
body {
  @apply(--layout-vertical); 
  @apply(--layout-fullbleed);  
}
```

in your styles instead of:

```
<body class="layout vertical fullbleed">
```

adding classes to your html elements.

It's a real shame as using classes is a much neater and intuitive way to apply layout styles.

Comment: I'm not sure how I didn't find this before. This is correct and got rid of all the bothersome console warnings.